# Trying to setup a Ghost blog with Buster

Tags: github-pages, ghost-blog

I'm trying to set up a static Ghost blog with Github hosting using the Buster Static generator. I've tried various instructions including:

https://stefanscherer.github.io/setup-ghost-for-github-pages/
 http://blog.sunnyg.io/2015/09/24/ghost-with-github/

But when I get to the "buster generate" command I get the following output in terminal.
It is running fine locally.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
buster generate
--2016-03-07 23:53:11--  http://localhost:2368/
Resolving localhost... ::1, 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost|::1|:2368... failed: Connection refused.
Connecting to localhost|127.0.0.1|:2368... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 4508 (4.4K) [text/html]
Saving to: '/Users/philip/Development/Node/ghost-0.7.8/static/index.html'

fixing links in  /Users/philip/Development/Node/ghost-0.7.8/static/index.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/buster", line 9, in <module>
load_entry_point('buster==0.1.3', 'console_scripts', 'buster')()
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/buster/buster.py", line 90, in main
newtext = fixLinks(filetext, parser)
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/buster/buster.py", line 64, in fixLinks
d = PyQuery(bytes(bytearray(text, encoding='utf-8')), parser=parser)
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyquery/pyquery.py", line 226, in __init__
elements = fromstring(context, self.parser)
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyquery/pyquery.py", line 90, in fromstring
result = custom_parser(context)
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lxml/html/__init__.py", line 867, in fromstring
doc = document_fromstring(html, parser=parser, base_url=base_url, **kw)
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lxml/html/__init__.py", line 752, in document_fromstring
value = etree.fromstring(html, parser, **kw)
File "src/lxml/lxml.etree.pyx", line 3213, in lxml.etree.fromstring (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:82934)
File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1819, in lxml.etree._parseMemoryDocument (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:124533)
File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1707, in lxml.etree._parseDoc (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:123074)
File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1079, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseDoc (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:117114)
File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 573, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:110510)
File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 683, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:112276)
File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 624, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:111367)lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: None
```

Comment: This doesn't really help, but I have seen multiple people with problems with buster in the last few months. I am guessing since the last commit was a year and a half ago and may others creating issues saying it isn't working, it may be broken now :(. Would love to know if you get it to work though.

Comment: I did in fact get it working! 
However, instead of doing the 'Quick Install' that was recommended on so many other blogs, I instead did the 'Developer Install' from git here
https://github.com/TryGhost/Ghost

Also, I've noticed some blogs recommended just using 
'buster generate' but this didn't work for me and had to specify a url using
'buster generate --domain=http://localhost:2368'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comment, I did get in working however instead of just doing the 'Quick Install' recommended by many, I went the route of the 'Developer Install' guide here https://github.com/TryGhost/Ghost using the Stable branch.

After you run through that (with your local server running), in another terminal, run

```
$ buster setup
<Enter git repo>
$ buster generate --domain=localhost:2368
$ buster deploy (or as most sane people prefer, just git push)
```

Full instructions here: http://phil-a.github.io/getting-ghost-running-on-github-with-buster